# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13 Incorrect syntax near '?'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sp-send-dbmail

I am struggling with a small piece of code.

the code runs fine in normal ssms but seems to fail when I put it into a step for mailing?

It just list tables and counts, have been doing it manually for too long.
I am trying to create Jobs so as the data is updated, the counts can be mailed to repsective person per server.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name = 'dbmail',
@recipients='random@needsthese.com',
@subject = 'those counts you want',
@body = 'these are count changes',
@execute_query_database = 'nbdb',
@query = 'CREATE TABLE #counts
(
    table_name varchar(255),
    row_count int
)

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable @command1='INSERT #counts (table_name, row_count) 
SELECT ''?'', COUNT(*) FROM ?'

SELECT table_name, row_count FROM #counts ORDER BY table_name, row_count DESC'
```

Comment: From the code highlighting I see some quotation issues, do you see them too?

Comment: Agree with Patrick. Are you sure this code runs fine in SSMS ?

Comment: I have the ' for the @command1 else I get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INSERT'." error in ssms. It does run fine as is above in ssms even with ("?") on the select statment. Should secify the query variable runs fine in ssms not the entire sp_send_mail one

Answer (score 0):

Modify it to this below(just add the quotes at the proper places)

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name = 'dbmail',
@recipients='random@needsthese.com',
@subject = 'those counts you want',
@body = 'these are count changes',
@execute_query_database = 'nbdb',
@query = 'CREATE TABLE #counts
(
    table_name varchar(255),
    row_count int
)

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable @command1=''INSERT #counts (table_name, row_count) 
SELECT ''?'', COUNT(*) FROM ?''

SELECT table_name, row_count FROM #counts ORDER BY table_name, row_count DESC'
```

Comment: Hi, while this parses and runs, the query statement gives the same error. A senior at the office has informed me that sp_send_mails cannot use local variables and hence the sp_MSforeachtable '?' variable cannot be used. seperating the steps enabled the mail with results. cheers